# How to show that $\mbox{MAut}(\mathcal{C})$ and $\gamma\mbox{Aut}(\mathcal{C})$ are groups?

Tags: group-theory, coding-theory, automorphism-group

I know how to prove a certain set is a group provided such set is basic such as $\mathbb{Z}$ under some binary operation.  But I am confused with this

How to show that $\mbox{MAut}(\mathcal{C})$ and $\gamma\mbox{Aut}(\mathcal{C})$ are groups?

Where the set of monomial matrices that map a code $\mathcal{C}$ to itself forms a group of $\mbox{MAut}(\mathcal{C})$ called the monomial automorphism group of $\mathcal{C}$. The set of maps of the form $M\gamma$, where $M$ is the monomial matrix and $\gamma$ is a field automorphism, that map $\mathcal{C}$ to itself forms the group $\Gamma\mbox{Aut}(\mathcal{C})$, called automorphism group of $\mathcal{C}$.

Can someone help me with this? I would appreciate this.  I don't know how the elements look like in this sets $\mbox{MAut}(\mathcal{C})$ and $\gamma\mbox{Aut}(\mathcal{C})$.

Comment: What's the _definition_ of the word "group"???????

Comment: A group is a set  with binary operation satisfying the existence of closure property, inverse property, identity property and the associative property.

Comment: Well then that's what you need to show: the composition of any two elements is an element and the inverse of any element is an element.